# Elasticsearch how to match documents for which the field tokens are a sub-set of the query tokens

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl

I have a keyword/key-phrase field I tokenize using standard analyser. I want this field to match if if there is a search phrase that has all tokens of this field in it.

For example if the field value is "veni, vidi, vici" and the search phrase is "Ceaser veni,vidi,vici" I want this search phrase to match but search phrase "veni, vidi" not match.

I also need "vidi, veni, vici" (weird!) to match. So the positions and ordering of the terms is not really important. A phrase match would not quite work for me I think.

I can use "bool query" with "minimum_should_match" parameter for this specific example but that is not really what I want as minimum should match is about ratio/number of tokens in the search phrase.

Comment: I am not sure if this will work but you can try search keyword as +vidi +veni, +vici. https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html

Comment: @NMK: I should probably have said, this is for a global search input on a website. So, the search phrase can be anything. I can't really extract tokens from the search that I can apply + operator to. It will have to be based on the field I have, not the search term

Comment: and even when that one "+ceaser +veni +vidi +vici" would fail cuz "+ceaser" is missing ;-(

Comment: I believe you can't do this because you want to invert the search. You cannot do this as you can search only for data which is indexed. There is no "get all the indexed phrases and check if they are contained in the input" query

Comment: @mbudnik That's what I thought really. Wasn't very hopeful when posting this :)

Comment: I had such strange requirements too, but i think in your case you have to write your own Query in Lucene. Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21163884/elasticsearch-match-every-position-only-once Perhaps you can ask: Why a customer who searches for "veni, vidi" shold not be interessated in  "Ceaser veni,vidi,vici" result. I even do some semantic analyzing with elasticsearch, because we had such requirements...

Comment: @Gizzmo: It is just one aspect of the search really. Along with a complex search query, the plan is to  use a field for prioritizing some documents for specific search terms which are analysed periodically. More of a fine-tuning requirement. Would be ideal if I could do it, have some workarounds and different approaches in mind.

Comment: To simplify the problem, what you want is to match documents for which the field tokens are a  sub-set of the query tokens. It's not possible I don't think in an efficient way through ES Search API. Depending on your requirements a Bloom filter might be a possible solution

Comment: @sean I think i will change the title to that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure ES solution would go like this. You will need two requests.

1) First you need to pass user query through [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/indices-analyze.html) to get all the search tokens.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze' -d '
{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "Ceaser veni,vidi,vici"
}'
```

you will get 4 tokens *ceaser*, *veni*, *vidi*, *vici* . You need to pass these tokens as an array to next `search` request.

2) We need to search for documents whose tokens are **subset** of search tokens.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "query": {
                "match": {
                  "title": "Ceaser veni,vidi,vici"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "script": {
                "script": "if(search_tokens.containsAll(doc['title'].values)){return true;}",
                "params": {
                  "search_tokens": [
                    "ceaser",
                    "veni",
                    "vidi",
                    "vici"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here job of first `match query` inside the filter is to narrow down the documents on which script should run. `containsAll` method will check if the documents tokens are `sublist` of search tokens. This will be slow but will do the job with your current set up. One big improvement you can do is store tokens as an array so that `doc['title'].values` can be replaced with that field which will improve the script.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No built-in solution but this works:

1. Add an extra field with the number of terms in the field for each document. So in your "veni, vidi, vici" example, you would have a field like "field_term_count" : 3.
2. Perform a separate match search for each token in the search query.
3. Sum the number of searches that matched for each document with at least one match (e.g. a hashtable with key of document ID and value of count).
4. Compare the number of matches in 3  to the "field_term_count" field for each of the documents with matches. If they are equal then the document is a match.

Then "Ceaser veni,vidi,vici" will match but the search phrases "veni, vidi" will not, as desired. It should be quite fast for reasonable numbers of matches.

Comment: Not sure if this works. If the field is "veni, vidi, vici" and search phrase is "Ceaser veni, vidi" it should not match. The filter would include "veni, vidi, vici" but I would still need to use something like minimum should match query to filter out "veni, vidi, vici".

Comment: Yes you need to use a Boolean match query  ("operator": "and"). This gives the desired behavior, "Ceaser veni, vidi" won't match.

Comment: That means "Ceaser  said veni, vidi, vici" won't match either though. Using "and" operator would require all search terms to match , wouldn't it ? It really takes us back to the original problem

Comment: Well, this is all good, but i am actually looking for a pure Elasticsearch solution.

Comment: There is no built-in method to do this in elasticsearch, you will need to implement my solution either as a script (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/modules-scripting.html) or in your post-processing code.