# ElasticSearch Match whole document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index like this:

```
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
        "properties": {
            "key_words": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "english", "search_analyzer": "english", "index": True},
            "name": {"type": "text", "index": False},
        }
    }
```

this index contains the topic names and keywords which should be matched to relate this topic to some text. So I need to make a search by topics index using the long text and find all topics which have a full match. For example, if I have these topics in index:

```
{"name": "a", "key_words": "World cup"}
{"name": "b", "key_words": "Gaming cup"}
{"name": "c", "key_words": "Cup"}
```

And text:

```
The World Championship, some country win the Cup on tennis!
```

I want to make the query using the "text", which will match only "a" and "c" documents, because of all keywords from the document present in the text.

Can someone please help me with building this query?
ES version: 6.8

Comment: Is there a certain limit on the amount of keywords in key_words? also could you explain why you choose to use the english analyzer?, it might be worth considering not using it if theres no real need as it will make your problem easier to solve.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082284/elasticsearch-how-to-match-documents-for-which-the-field-tokens-are-a-sub-set-of

Comment: @tomslabbaert because I'm working only with the English language, to filter unnecessary words and to use only the root of the word. No there is no any limits of words in key_words

Comment: Which ES version you are using?

Comment: @SathishkumarRakkiasamy 6.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Jaspreet Chahal for the link in the comments, I found the solution there. 
I changed the mapping so it starts looking like this:

```
{
"mappings": {
    "_doc": {
        "properties": {
            "key_words": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "english", "search_analyzer": "english", "index": True, "fielddata": True},
            "name": {"type": "text", "index": False},
        }
    }
}
```

}

and I needed to do the search in two calls, first is to analyze the text and generate 
the tokens

```
analyzed = await el.indices.analyze(body={"analyzer": "english", "text": "The World Championship, some country win the Cup on tennis!"})
```

and then the call with a script condition

```
{
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{
                    "match": {
                        "key_words": desc
                    }}],
                "filter": {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "source": "if(params.search_tokens.containsAll(doc['key_words'].values)){return true;}",
                            "lang": "painless",
                            "params": {
                                "search_tokens": [an['token'] for an in analyzed['tokens']]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        },
        "_source": ["_id"]
    }
```